# Finding $\small{\min\limits_{ab+bc+ca=1}\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}- \sqrt{2-abc}.}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, radicals, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Find the minimal value of expression
$$P=\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}- \sqrt{2-abc}.$$
By $a=b=1;c=0$ I get $P=2\sqrt{3}$ so we need to prove that$$\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}\ge \sqrt{2-abc}+2\sqrt{3}. $$
I thought of Lagrange multiplier method.

We can split inequality into two cases.

$\bullet$ If $a=0;bc=1,$ it's $\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}\ge 2\sqrt{3},$which is easy be AM-GM.

$\bullet$  $abc\neq0,$ we consider$$f(a,b,c,\lambda)=\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc}-2\sqrt{3}+\lambda(ab+ac+bc-1).$$ and $(a,b,c)$ be an inside minimum point of $f$.

Thus, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=0,$$ which gives
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+2}}+\frac{bc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+2\lambda(b+c)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+2}}+\frac{ac}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+2\lambda(a+c)\\&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c+2}}+\frac{ba}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+2\lambda(b+a).
\end{align*}
Now, let in this point $a\neq b$ and $a\neq c$ and we need to prove $b=c.$

From here, I was confusing in case $abc=2$ and how to continue my idea.

Hope you help me. Also, all idea and comment are welcome.

**Update 1.** Michael Rozenberg has almost solved it by LM. Is there another approach?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. We assume $a,b,c$ are nonnegative.
Let us denote the constraint set as $$C=\{(a,b,c): ab\leq 1, a\geq 0,b\geq 0, c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b} \}.$$
Note that $-\sqrt{2-abc}\geq -\sqrt{2} $. Thus
$$\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc} \geq$$ $$\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2}$$

Hence,
$$\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C} \sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc} \geq$$
$$\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C} \sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2}$$
Let us define $f(a,b,c)=\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2}$ and $f(a,b,c)= f_1(a,b)+f_2(c)$ where $f_1(a,b)=\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}$ and $f_2(c)=\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2}$.

Note that $$\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f(a,b,c)=\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f_1(a,b)+f_2(c)\geq$$ $$\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f_1(a,b)+\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f_2(c) \geq $$ $$\min\limits_{ab\leq 1 \& a,b,c\geq 0}f_1(a,b) + \min\limits_{ab\leq 1 \& a,b,c\geq 0}f_2(c)$$.

It is clear that $\min\limits_{ab\leq 1 \& a,b,c\geq 0}f_2(c)=0$ for $c=0$.

For $\min\limits_{ab\leq 1 \& a,b,c\geq 0}f_1(a,b)$, we have to find the minimum of $\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}$ for $a\geq 0, b>0, ab\leq 1$. Here, we can use Langrange multipliers and get the minimum at $a=b=1$. As a result we get $\min\limits_{ab\leq 1 \& a,b,c\geq 0}f_1(a,b)=2\sqrt{3}$.

This shows  $\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f(a,b,c)\geq 2\sqrt{3}$. Since $(1,1,0)\in C$ and $f(1,1,0)=2\sqrt{3}$, we deduce that $\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f(a,b,c)= 2\sqrt{3}$.
Thus,
$$\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C} \sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc} \geq \min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f(a,b,c)= 2\sqrt{3} $$

So $\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc}$  attains its minimum at $(1,1,0)$, which $2\sqrt{3}$ because $(1,1,0) \in C$.

Comment: $\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C}f(a,b,c)= 2\sqrt{3}$ is not true. For example, $a =3/4, b = 1/2, c = 1/2$, we have $\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2} - 2\sqrt{3} \approx -0.05$; The reason is that your $\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2-abc}$ can not be relaxed to $\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are right @river. I have checked my arguments. My mistake results from the assumption that the minimum of $f_1$ with the constraints $ab\leq 1$ is  $2\sqrt{3}$. The minimum of $f_1$ is $2\sqrt{2}$ (obviously for $a=0,b=0)$. Hence, I get $\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C} f(a,b,c)\geq 2\sqrt{2}$, which blows my solution.  I think $\min\limits_{(a,b,c)\in C} f(a,b,c)$ happens for $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ which is clearly do not coincide with that of the given expression.

Comment: Hope you can fix it or given another proof.

Answer (score 1):

By your work $$\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{a+2}}+\tfrac{bc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(b+c)=\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{b+2}}+\tfrac{ac}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(a+c)=\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{c+2}}+\tfrac{ba}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(b+a)=0$$ or
$$\tfrac{a}{2\sqrt{a+2}}+\tfrac{abc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(ab+ac)=\tfrac{b}{2\sqrt{b+2}}+\tfrac{abc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(ab+cb)=\tfrac{c}{2\sqrt{c+2}}+\tfrac{abc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}+\lambda(ac+bc)=0$$ or
$$\tfrac{a}{2\sqrt{a+2}}+\lambda(ab+ac)=\tfrac{b}{2\sqrt{b+2}}+\lambda(ab+cb)=\tfrac{c}{2\sqrt{c+2}}+\lambda(ac+bc)=-\tfrac{abc}{2\sqrt{2-abc}}.$$
Now, let in this point $a\neq b$ and $a\neq c$.

Thus, we have $$\tfrac{a}{2\sqrt{a+2}}+\lambda(ab+ac)=\tfrac{b}{2\sqrt{b+2}}+\lambda(ab+cb)$$ or
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2}}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2}}+2\lambda c(a-b)=0$$ or
$$(a-b)\left(\frac{ab+2(a+b)}{\sqrt{(a+2)(b+2)}\left(a\sqrt{b+2}+b\sqrt{a+2}\right)}+2\lambda c\right)=0$$ or $$\frac{ab+2(a+b)}{\sqrt{(a+2)(b+2)}\left(a\sqrt{b+2}+b\sqrt{a+2}\right)}+2\lambda c=0$$ by the similar way we obtain $$\frac{ac+2(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+2)(c+2)}\left(a\sqrt{c+2}+c\sqrt{a+2}\right)}+2\lambda b=0,$$ which gives
$$\frac{b(ab+2(a+b))}{\sqrt{(a+2)(b+2)}\left(a\sqrt{b+2}+b\sqrt{a+2}\right)}=\frac{c(ac+2(a+c))}{\sqrt{(a+2)(c+2)}\left(a\sqrt{c+2}+c\sqrt{a+2}\right)}$$ or
$$b(ab+2(a+b))\left(a(c+2)+c\sqrt{(a+2)(c+2)}\right)=$$
$$=c(ac+2(a+c))\left(a(b+2)+b\sqrt{(a+2)(b+2)}\right)$$ or
$$a\left(b(c+2)(ab+2(a+b))-c(b+2)(ac+2(a+c))\right)+$$
$$+bc\sqrt{a+2}\left((ab+2(a+b))\sqrt{c+2}-(ac+2(a+c))\sqrt{b+2}\right)=0$$ or
$$(b-c)\left(a(abc+2(ab+ac+bc)+4(a+b+c))+\tfrac{bc\sqrt{a+2}\left(a^2(bc+2b+2c+4)+4abc+4(2ab+2ac+bc)+8(2a+b+c)\right)}{(ab+2(a+b))\sqrt{c+2}+(ac+2(a+c))\sqrt{b+2}}\right)=0,$$ which gives $b=c$ and it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of two variables.

Can you end it now?

Comment: I can do it. Thank you for your help. Also, have you found Holder using?

Comment: @Dragon boy Yes, of course. I'll do it later. Very busy now...

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{b+2}+\sqrt{c+2}\ge \sqrt{2-abc}+2\sqrt{3}.\tag{1}$$

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$. We have
$$\frac13 \le ab \le 1, \quad c \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}. \tag{2}$$

By AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{a + 2} + \sqrt{b + 2}
 &= \sqrt{a + 2 + b + 2 + 2\sqrt{(a + 2)(b + 2)}}\\[6pt]
 &\ge \sqrt{a + 2 + b + 2 + 2\cdot \frac{2(a + 2)(b + 2)}{a + 2 + b + 2}}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Using (2), we have
$$\sqrt{c + 2} - \sqrt{2} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c + 2} + \sqrt{2}}
\ge \frac{c}{\sqrt{1/\sqrt{3} + 2} + \sqrt{2}} \ge \frac{50}{151}c. \tag{4}$$

We have
$$\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2 - abc} = \frac{abc}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2 - abc}}
\ge \frac{abc}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}} \ge \frac{6}{17}abc. \tag{5}$$

From (1) and (3)-(5), it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{a + 2 + b + 2 + 2\cdot \frac{2(a + 2)(b + 2)}{a + 2 + b + 2}}
+ \frac{50}{151}c + \frac{6}{17}abc \ge 2\sqrt{3}. \tag{6}$$

Let $p = a + b, q = ab$. We have
$$1/3 \le q \le 1, \quad p^2 \ge 4q.$$

Using $c = \frac{1 - ab}{a + b} = \frac{1 - q}{p}$, (6) is written as
$$f(q) := \sqrt{p + 4 + \frac{4(q + 2p + 4)}{p + 4}} + \frac{50}{151}\cdot \frac{1 - q}{p}
+ \frac{6}{17}\cdot q \cdot \frac{1 - q}{p} - 2\sqrt{3} \ge 0. \tag{7}$$

It suffices to prove that $f(q) \ge 0$ for $1/3 \le q \le \min(1, p^2/4)$.

Clearly, $f(q)$ is concave.

If $p\le 2$, it is not difficult to prove that $f(1/3) \ge 0$ and $f(p^2/4) \ge 0$. Thus, $f(q) \ge 0$ for all $q \in [1/3, p^2/4]$.

If $p > 2$, it is not difficult to prove that $f(1/3) \ge 0$ and $f(1) \ge 0$.
Thus, $f(q)\ge 0$ for all $q \in [1/3, 1]$.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

For $k=\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}-1$ by Holder we obtain:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+2}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+2)^2(ka+b+c)^3\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(a+2)(ka+b+c)\right)^3$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(a+2)(ka+b+c)\right)^3\geq\left(\sqrt{2-abc}+2\sqrt3\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+2)^2(ka+b+c)^3,$$ which save the case of the equality occurring.

Now, we can try to use $uvw$.

I hope it will help.